# OpenAL Soft 40964 in alcOpenDevice: AL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, openal, openal-soft

When running my audio application, ported from Windows, on Ubuntu Virtualbox, it reports the following:

```
Devices found:
OpenAL Soft

OpenAL Soft 40964 in alcOpenDevice: AL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

The line it runs on:

```
ALCdevice device = alcOpenDevice( NULL ); // Also tried "OpenAL Soft"
```

Ubuntu audio is working properly. What am I missing?

CMakeLists:

```
target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    "myengine"
    "openal"
)
```

I installed `libopenal1` on the target VM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the `alGetError()` will return this error before a context is created. Starting from `alcMakeContextCurrent()` I can use this function to check for errors.

It now plays audio!

So for `alcOpenDevice()` and `alcCreateContext()` I had to comment out the `alGetError()` error checking. Though I could still check whether the device was opened successfully using `if( !device )`